# How can I identify the completion of batch program in a windows environment using java and shell programming

Tags: java, shell, process, exec

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start C:/Empire/Intranet/Redbook/Monthly/runmonthly_Dev.cmd");

//Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start C:/Empire/Intranet/Redbook/Monthly/runmonthly_Dev.cmd");
p.waitFor();
while(p.exitValue() == 0){
}
```

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 0):

Not like that. You've already waited for the process to complete, when you called `waitFor()`. The loop that executes until the exit value is zero will run forever if it wasn't, but the exit value will never change. The loop is pointless. Remove it.

And if you want to wait for the program rather than the batch file to complete, remove the `start`.